# Подсказки у заполнителя в своих сниппетах VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Хочу при выборе заполнителя прописать подсказки (см скрин)

Можно ли в VS code так сделать и как если можно?

Имеем сниппет

```
    "Мой код": {
        "prefix": "мк",
        "body": [
            "мойкод'${1|первый,второй,третий|}'",
        ],
        "description": "мой код"
    },
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]